# Why does k8s allow to set minAvailable = 0 in PDB?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

When I am trying to drain the EKS k8s node, I am getting error that
PDB minAvailable value is set to 1, so the workaround for that is to
either increase the replicas or in some rare cases(I have this app
where I can not have two replicas of admin pod) we have to make PDB
minAvailable value to 0.

Question is why does even minAvailable value 0 is allowed to make in
PDB?Why does k8s allows to set us minAvailable value to 0 instead of giving warning or error? Does it make any sense having minAvailable value 0 in PBD or not?
should we not at all have PDB in such case?

Answer (score 0):

There could be **multiple** reasons for that however i am putting one scenario that came into my head after reading the question.

Suppose you are running the **RC** or **Deployment** with **PDB** set to **minAvailable**. In many cases, it is required to scale down the Deployment replicas to **0**.

Now if PDB is set to **1**, scaling down to zero won't work even if you will try it manually. In that case, you have to delete the PDB configuration and scale down the application.

When required you have to create a new PDB out of YAML and apply the config.

We are running a few workloads with the scale-down config to **zero** those get scaled-up serverless functions with **Knative** on K8s.

You can check the K8s PDB controller code here : https://github.com/mortent/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/disruption/disruption.go#L644